# Alternative to Promise.all for loading many resources simultaneously?

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise, fetch-api, promise.all

I have the following code, which works:

```
interface MyImages {
  apple: HTMLImageElement,
  banana: HTMLImageElement,
  carrot: HTMLImageElement
}

async function fetchImages(): Promise<MyImages> {
  const images = await Promise.all([
    asyncImageLoad("/images/apple.png"),
    asyncImageLoad("/images/banana.png"),
    asyncImageLoad("/images/carrot.png")
  ]);

  return {
    apple: images[0],
    banana: images[1],
    carrot: images[2]
  };
}
```

However, it's a bit verbose. Also, it's error-prone, because you have to match up the array indexes with the proper element.

I would *much* rather just do this:

```
async function fetchImages(): Promise<MyImages> {
  return {
    apple: await asyncImageLoad("/images/apple.png"),
    banana: await asyncImageLoad("/images/banana.png"),
    carrot: await asyncImageLoad("/images/carrot.png")
  };
}
```

This is much more concise, less error-prone, *but* unfortunately it synchronously queries each image.

That is, instead of sending all requests at once, this one first queries for the apple, awaits for it to return, then queries for the banana, awaits for it to return, and then finally queries the carrot image.

Is there any way to have the ergonomics of the latter with the performance of the former?

Comment: `const [apple, banana, carrot] = await Promise.all(...); return { apple, banana, carrot }`? Or you could start from the array `["apple", "banana", "carrot"]` and generate everything from that via e.g. `Object.fromEntries`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh thanks your first suggestion is pretty good! I'm not sure what you mean exactly with `Object.fromEntries` so I'll have to experiment a bit I think

Answer (score 2):

This alternative implementation of your function is based on @jonrsharpe's suggestion about using `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
async function fetchImages(): Promise<MyImages> {
  const sources = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"];
  const images = await Promise.all(
    sources.map(async source => {
      const image = await asyncImageLoad(`/images/${source}.png`);
      return [source, image];
    })
  );
  return Object.fromEntries(images);
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this working. Did you mean to `await` the `asyncImageLoad` function? If so, I think there needs to be an `await` keyword before `source`. Otherwise, `await` shouldn't be before `asyncImageLoad`.